# How to run multiple script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Can anyone help me with these?
I want all of it work but only the first one works.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();

  if( activeCell == "A1" )
  {
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
      if( i%2 == 0 )
        mysheet.getRange("A1:M1").setBackground("RED");
      else
        mysheet.getRange("A1:M1").setBackground("WHITE");

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
}


function onEdit1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();

  if( activeCell == "A2" )
  {
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
      if( i%2 == 0 )
        mysheet.getRange("A2:M2").setBackground("RED");
      else
        mysheet.getRange("A2:M2").setBackground("WHITE");

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
}

function onEdit2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mysheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();

  if( activeCell == "A3" )
  {
    for(var i=0;i<50;i++)
    {
      if( i%2 == 0 )
        mysheet.getRange("A3:M3").setBackground("RED");
      else
        mysheet.getRange("A3:M3").setBackground("WHITE");

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      Utilities.sleep(500);
    }
  }
}
```

I want the 3 of it blink

Comment: Anyone who can help me by editing my codes?
please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all three functions to run on edit, call them all from one function.

```
onEdit() {
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
}

function1() {
    // Do something
}

function2() {
    // Do something
}

function3() {
    // Do something
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's a far shorter way to do all three:

```
function onEdit() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = spreadsheet.getActiveCell();

    var col = cell.getColumn();
    var row = cell.getRow();

    if (col === 1 && sheet.getName() === 'Sheet1') {
    // If the edited cell is in column A (1) and on the correct sheet

        for (var num = 0; num < 50; num++) {

            var colour = num%2 === 0
                ? 'RED'
                : 'WHITE';
            // Using ? and : like this is called a ternary operation. It's a
            // shorter form of if. ifStatement ? true : false.

            sheet.getRange('A' + row + ':M' + row).setBackground(colour);
            // Get the range for the edited row and set the bg colour

            SpreadsheetApp.flush();
            Utilities.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have added to my answer.

Comment: Oh, I had to change `rows.indexOf(row)` to `rows.indexOf(row) !== -1`

Comment: I've made a change so that the code will only run on the specified sheet. :)

Comment: ooow okie okie.

Comment: Master, the first one was better for me cause I need to run more than 3 rows, because from your first codes when I type something in column 1 the row blinks when I put it, from A1 to last I think. But now only row 1 to 3 only hehe

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Could you try to explain again?

Comment: "Run more than three rows" I think is where I'm confused. Do you need to do this on every row?

Comment: Yes, in every row

Comment: but, thank you for the 2nd one it also helps, i just add from the list of rows 1, 2, 3 i add up to 50 i think that's enough. Thank you master!
Good thing you put a note in your codes
I understand easily if there is need to add.

Comment: Master, now my problem was this, I have your codes and another codes to hide row they both run individually but why it wont work when I combine them?
My problem was like my post. I want to run 2 codes at the same time.
I also try to change onEdit to other name so that they are not the same, but still it wont work.
Sorry, I cant post it now. It is said that there is a 2 days duration before I can post a question again. :)
I enjoy self studying java, Do you have any suggestion where I can easily learn it for free? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't know where to study Java. I use [w3](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript) as JavaScript references. To run many functions on edit, please examine the first part of my answer, before the edits.

Comment: hmm, Master, still only the blinking codes run the second code (hide rows) wont.